# What does this alphanumeric string mean in a CAPTCHA?

Tags: discussion, captcha

Is it me, or is the captcha checking a little tedious? It literally took me about a minute of clicking pictures before the system finally realized I wasn't a robot.

In any case, what does the alphanumeric string in the captcha mean?

[image]

Comment: I looked at your user name and was slowed down for a while, trying to decide whether I should post a comment.  Which proves that I'm not a robot.

Comment: Looks like a UUID, and looks like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: All kidding aside, the google captcha no longer requires you to identify a completely unreadable string, it now looks at how you use your mouse to click the checkbox.  Humans and bots don't do it the same way.

Comment: Everybody knows that's a guid. Only a robot would pretend not to know what it is. Robot.